# drawing d3.svg.arc element using data stored in array in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi i'm trying to multiple draw [coxcomb charts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNightingale-mortality.jpg). 
The code draws one such chart. [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/etheleon/Zawx4/)

The problem i ran into: how do I order my data such that it'll allow me to draw multiples of such charts?

```
//data
var data = [
    {"label": "January", "value": 150, "time": 1},
    {"label": "February", "value": 65, "time": 2},
    {"label": "March", "value": 50, "time": 3},
    {"label": "April", "value": 75, "time": 4},
    {"label": "May", "value": 150, "time": 5},
    {"label": "June", "value": 65, "time": 6}
];

//container
var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", 1000)
.attr("height", 1000);

var pi = Math.PI;

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(function(d,i) {return (0 + d.value); })
        .startAngle(function(d,i) { return ((d.time - 1) * 60 * pi / 180); })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return (d.time * 60 * pi / 180 ); });

var chartContainer = svg.append("g")
        .attr('class', 'some_class')
        .attr("transform", "translate(450, 300)");

chartContainer.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("class", "arc");
```

I thought perhaps I can order the data in the following manner:

```
var data2 = [
{label: "Rose.chart1", value: [150,65,50,75,150,65]}
{label: "Rose.chart2", value: [130,50,30,10,50,70]}
]
```

But that would mean i'll have to rewrite the following:

1.) defining the arc variable

```
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .innerRadius(0)
        .outerRadius(function(d,i) {return (0 + d.value); })
        .startAngle(function(d,i) { return ((d.time - 1) * 60 * pi / 180); })
        .endAngle(function(d) { return (d.time * 60 * pi / 180 ); });
```

2.) binding the data to the selection

```
chartContainer.selectAll("path")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("class", "arc");
```

I would think I'll probably need to enter the data object (data2), and again for the value element. 
pardon my description.

```
function(d.value) {???}
```

Answer (score 4):

First nest the data, as an array of arrays. So you'll have:

```
//data
var data = [
  [
    {"label": "January", "value": 150, "time": 1},
    {"label": "February", "value": 65, "time": 2},
    {"label": "March", "value": 50, "time": 3},
    {"label": "April", "value": 75, "time": 4},
    {"label": "May", "value": 150, "time": 5},
    {"label": "June", "value": 65, "time": 6}
  ],
  [
    {"label": "January", "value": 123, "time": 1},
    {"label": "February", "value": 62345, "time": 2},
    {"label": "March", "value": 5340, "time": 3},
    {"label": "April", "value": 72315, "time": 4},
    {"label": "May", "value": 11350, "time": 5},
    {"label": "June", "value": 6135, "time": 6}
  ],
];
```

Then nest the charts in a parent container that's bound to the data:

```
svg.selectAll(".charts")
  .data(data)
    .enter()
      .append("g")
      // Translate each chart based on 'i'
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + ((i+1) * 450) + ", 300)");
      .each(function(chartData, i) {
         var chartContainer = d3.select(this);// Selects the containing 'g'
         // The rest is what you already wrote
         chartContainer.selectAll("path")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("class", "arc");
      });
```